# How to move labels that was added programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, mouse, move

I have Xml file which stores names of objects. When I start the program, I load the object names and then make new label for each object name.

(I know there is posibility to move labels by using `_MouseMove()` and `_MouseDown()` methods, but it works only if I put the label by drag and drop in `[Project]` or create new label by `Label label = new Label();`. Generally:  when control object has his own name.)

So is there any posibility to move labels which was added by the code like here below?

```
public List<Activities> listOfActivities = new List<Activities>();

listOfActivities = XmlSerialization.ReadFromXmlFile<List<Activities>>("activities.txt");
foreach (Activities activity in listOfActivities)
{
   Point point = new Point(activity.xLabel, activity.yLabel);
   Label label = new Label();
   label.Text = activity.name;
   label.Location = point;
   label.Visible = true;
   this.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

Comment: You can keep your created labels in a `List<Label>` and then you can try to move them as you want

Comment: It works. Thank you!